# Rails 3.1 - has_and_belongs_to_many deprecated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got an application currently Rails 3.0.9, with a very simple many to many relationship:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :stores, :join_table => "users_stores"
end
```

I'm getting the following warning popping up all over the place:

DEPRECATION WARNING: Having additional attributes on the join table of a has_and_belongs_to_many association is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 3.1. Please use a has_many :through association instead.

The thing is, I don't have any extra attributes on the join table:

```
sqlite> .schema users_stores
CREATE TABLE "users_stores" ("user_id" integer, "store_id" integer);
```

Is has_and_belongs_to_many completely deprecated in Rails 3.1?  I tried an upgrade to 3.1 but I'm using some gems which haven't yet been updated, so I'm waiting a while longer, but ideally, I'd like my part of the code to be good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's deprecated, but still there. It doesn't *check* to see if you have attributes on the join table, it's just letting you know. It still works.

Comment: OK, nice simple answer!  Further to this, I've set ActiveSupport::Deprecation.silenced = true to avoid seeing this message repeated each time an rspec test is run.  Do you know if there is a more granular way to switch off deprecation warnings?

Comment: Would recommend to try to take the time time to refactor to has_many :through now.  Turning off deprecation warnings at all is to be avoided if at all possible.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant Is it `habtm` that's deprecated, or the extra attributes? The Rails guide says only the attributes are deprecated, not `habtm` itself. I could be misreading it, though.

Comment: `habtm` is not deprecated, the official Rails guide still recommends it: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many - So no need to refactor this and I also don't get any deprecation warnings.

Comment: @iGEL The deprecation warning depends on what you're actually doing: it *was* deprecated for the use case as described in the question, that's why the Rails developers put in the deprecation message saying to use has_many:through for join tables with additional data. The link you provide *specifically* states the same: "You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks, **or extra attributes on the join model**" (emphasis mine).