# rails model has_many :through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get my relationships worked out but I am having trouble using the associations.

So I have three models `Workout`, `Exercise` and `WorkoutExercise`. A workout should have many exercises and a exercise should have different workouts therefore I wrote:

```
class Workout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workout_exercises
  has_many :exercises, :through => :workout_exercises
end

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :workout_exercises
  has_many :workouts, :through => :workout_exercises
end

class WorkoutExercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :exercise
  belongs_to :workout
end
```

I am running some tests but the tests aren't passing once I create a workout, exercise and then join them in the workout_exercise class. It won't let me access the exercises in the workout like this:

```
Workout.create
Exercise.create
WorkoutExercise.create(:workout => Workout.first, :exercise => Exercise.first)
work = Workout.first
work.exercises.count #This line causes the error: undefined method exercises
```

My database tables look like this:

```
class CreateWorkouts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :workouts do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.float :score
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end 

class CreateExercises < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :exercises do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.float :value
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateWorkoutExercises < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :workout_exercises do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When I run this tests it says `exercises` is undefined. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you run your migrations? Please show us your 3 tables. And I think you should ignore Yanhao's suggestion for a while. Your code seems to be correct so you don't have to change it for now. You are missing something else.

Comment: @Ashitaka I added the tables above, would it have something to do with the CreateWorkoutExercises table is empty? This is my first time doing using habtm.

Comment: Ok, so that was it. You were missing the ids that established the connection between the two tables. You'll probably want to recreate your migrations now. I think `rake db:reset` will do the job (it will delete all your records though).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so your WorkoutExercises table can't be empty. This is how it should look:

```
class CreateWorkoutExercises < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :WorkoutExercises do |t|
      t.integer :exercise_id, :null => false
      t.integer :workout_id, :null => false

      t.timestamps
    end

    # I only added theses indexes so theoretically your database queries are faster.
    # If you don't plan on having many records, you can leave these 2 lines out.
    add_index :WorkoutExercises, :exercise_id
    add_index :WorkoutExercises, :workout_id
  end
end
```

Also, you can name this table whatever you'd like, it doesn't have to be WorkoutExercises.
**However**, if you were using a has_and_belongs_to_many relationship, your table would have to mandatorily be named ExercisesWorkout. Notice how Exercises comes before Workout. The names have to be alphabetically ordered. Don't ask me why, it's just a Rails convention.

So, in this case, you'll do fine with your table being named WorkoutExercises. But if I were you, I'd change it to ExercisesWorkout, just in case, so that you never get it wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Ashitaka. In Rails 4, the column and index migration can be written in one line `t.references :exercise, index: true`

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks OK. Bug maybe `has_and_belongs_to_many` is a better choice. See [Choosing Between has_many :through and has_and_belongs_to_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)

Comment: I believe has_and_belongs_to_many associations are being deprecated. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850111/rails-3-1-has-and-belongs-to-many-deprecated