# Rails: has_many :through without additional table

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a model named Container. This model just has a list of associated Links. So I created tables containers, links and containers_links. Now I want to connect my two models. So I did

```
class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :links, :through => :containers_links
end

class Links < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :containers, :through => :containers_links
end
```

But I have an error because I don't have reflection with containers_links in my model. I can add something like

```
has_many :containers_links
```

But I don't have a model ContainersLinks (and I don't want to create one). What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship

```
class Container < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :links
end

class Links < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :containers
end
```

But you still need to create [join table](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#updating-the-schema).

Comment: It still works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850111/rails-3-1-has-and-belongs-to-many-deprecated

Comment: I treat it as deprecated but it's a long discussion about opinions.

Comment: Anyway seems like it's the best way to do what i want.