# Rails has_many :through difficulties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, associations

I just can't figure out why this association isn't working... I'm pretty sure this is all right but can't find the typo

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lessons_units, :foreign_key => "lesson_id",
                           :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :units, :through => :lessons_units
end

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lessons_units, :foreign_key => "unit_id",
                           :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :lessons, :through => :lessons_units
end


class LessonsUnits < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :lesson_id, :unit_id

  belongs_to :unit
  belongs_to :lesson

  validates :unit_id, :presence => true
  validates :lesson_id, :presence => true
end
```

Then at console

```
1.9.3p194 :001 > Unit.lessons.build
NoMethodError: undefined method `lessons' for #<Class:0x007fe733c29f30>
from /Users/robert/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
```

And in the App

```
  def create
    @unit = Unit.find(params[:unit_id])
    @lesson = @unit.lessons.build(params[:lesson])
```

Result:

```
uninitialized constant Unit::LessonsUnit
```

Comment: You should look into using a [`has_and_belongs_to_many` association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_and_belongs_to_many-association). It won't solve this problem, but it will simplify your code.

Comment: I believe has_and_belongs_to_many is depreciated as of 3.1 so I'm avoiding it when possible. I agree its cleaner though.

Comment: It was my understanding that storing extra data in the join table (i.e. anything more than the two ids) was deprecated, but the association type wasn't. There's nothing about deprecation in the [Rails 3.1 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html).

Comment: Read into it, you are right. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850111/rails-3-1-has-and-belongs-to-many-deprecated

Comment: You *can* accept your own answer, after the required waiting period.  Editing "solved" into the title isn't a solution, so to speak.  Of course, rewarding those who tried to help you is always nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LessonsUnits - 

class LessonsUnits < ActiveRecord::Base
```

should be singular:

```
class LessonsUnit < ActiveRecord::Base
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out. Its because my link model ends with an 's' - rails was translating it into a singular. Noticed it because the error showed the model without the 's' - Unit::LessonsUnit instead of Unit::LessonsUnits

Editing the relationship to :lessons_unitss fixes it... I'm going to go through and rename the model to not be plural.

Comment: In the future it will benefit you to explain your issue in context. In this case by trying to abstract the problem away from your controller you caused another unrelated problem that appeared to be the core of your question. Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: Thanks for the time to make the answer. I really appreciate it. I did spend like an hour on this in the controller before dropping back to the console, I guess I need to be more careful when I try to simplify. :)

Comment: You should have accepted your own answer; you solved this on your own :)

Comment: It said I couldn't accept it for two days. So I didn't want to waste anyones time coming in here. He had it right either way.