# How to find any existing tags through a has_many - through relationship, before storing a blog post to the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The title from the question might be really vague but let me explain:

Let's say I have two simple models `BlogPost` and `Tag`

Content model:

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blog_tags
  has_many :tags, through: :blog_tags

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags
end
```

Tag model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blog_tags
  has_many :blog_posts, through: :blog_tags

  validates_uniqueness_of :title
end
```

Blog Tag model:

```
class BlogTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog_post
  belongs_to :tag
end
```

From my blogposts controller I'm initiating the tags in the `new` action. This is made possible by the `accept_nested_attributes_for` in my `BlogPost` model.

```
 class BlogPostsController < ApplicationController

   def new
     @blog_post = BlogPost.new
     @tags = @blog_post.tags.build
   end

   def create
     @blog_post = BlogPost.new(blog_post_params)

     if @blog_post.save
       redirect_to root_url
     else
       render :new
     end
   end

 private

   def blog_post_params
     params.require(:blog_post).permit(
       :text, :image,
       tags_attributes: [:title, :id]
     )
   end
 end
```

It's all nice and good.

**Scenario #1: No tags in the database**

Result:

- The BlogPost gets created
- The tags are getting created
- the has_many_and_belongs_to associations are set correctly

**Scenario #2: With existing tags in the database - using the same tag twice**

Result:
The BlogPost doesn't get created due to a duplicate tag name.

What I want

- The BlogPost gets created
- The tags are found (?!?!?!)
- the has_many_and_belongs_to associations are set correctly

How to achieve scenario #2 nicely?

**EDITS:**

- Edited has_many_and_belongs_to to has_many :through

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `has_and_belongs_to_many` is deprecated since rails 3.1.
( [Rails 3.1 - has_and_belongs_to_many deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850111/rails-3-1-has-and-belongs-to-many-deprecated) )

I think it would be a better idea to implement it with a `has_many :through` relation, and perform all your checks on the intermediate model.

Comment: Yeah, got that. What do those validations look like? Because I have a `blog_post_tags` intermediate model now. And it only has a `tag_id` and a `blog_post_id`.

Comment: See original question